# bash while loop using echo as the loop counter

Tags: bash, shell, loops, while-loop, command

hello I have a command

```
echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l')
```

this returns a integer value I need to while loop over it but can't seem to figure out who to do that.

```
while echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l') -g 1; do

echo stuff

done
```

Comment: What is the intention of the -g param?

And what is the output of the command

`echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l') -g 1`

and

`echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l')`

Comment: What do you mean by "while loop over it"?  Do you need to call that long command on each iteration?  Do you iterate until the integer is zero, or what?

Comment: Sorry the output of the command is a integer like 6 or 10 ect. I want to loop over it while output > 1. Also it needs to call said command each loop to make sure it's still greater then 1. Thanks for the help.

Comment: `while` keeps looping as long as that condition is true (returns a 0 exit status). So what exactly do you observe when executing your code above? That the code inside of the while loop is never executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi You can try like this,

```
declare -i value
value=`echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l')`
while [ "$value" -gt 1 ]; do
    echo stuff
    value=`echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l')`
done
```

OR we can use it like,

```
declare -i value
while : ; do
  value=`echo $(ssh dema@10.0.1.100 'zfs list -o name -t snapshot | grep tank/dema@Daily_$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") | wc -l')`
  [[ "$value" -gt 1 ]] || break
  echo stuff
done
```